# one to one chat application with angular and spring boot?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, chat, real-time, spring-websocket

Can any buddy help in implementing an one to one chat application in Angular and spring boot as a backend with websocket or can anyone suggest me how to do that if he has any experience .
Basically i want to implement a chat application in my website where all users can communicate with each other through this chat.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you specifics, but you should check out this websockets deep dive: https://www.ably.io/concepts/websockets. Additionally, a chat app guide like this might come in handy https://www.ably.io/tutorials/react-native-presence-publish-subscribe#title

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the guidelines on how to answer questions. In particular: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."